# Is there a software that can calculate collision cross-sections involving molecules with several atoms?

Tags: software, software-recommendations, q-chem, apple-operating-system

What software currently can be accessibly used to calculate collision cross section using the geometries obtained from DFT? In my case, Q-Chem is used for geometry optimization.

The goal is to compute cross-section which can be compared with CCS (collisional cross-section) obtained from Ion Mobility Mass Spectrometry experiments where gases like N<sub>2</sub>, Ar or He could be used. I found relevant papers in *[Organometallics](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.organomet.8b00128)* and *[PCCP](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.organomet.8b00128)* as examples of calculations of CCS.

I'm aware of iMos, but I haven't tested it yet. Is there any other software which is capable of performing this calculation?

Comment: +1. Just added some tags since this is asking for a [tag:software-recommendations] question. Would "cross-section" be an appropriate tag instead of the more specific "collisional-cross-section" ?

Comment: @NikeDattani, could you please review edited question? I have also added two references for papers where such calculations were accomplished.

Comment: Sorry for not replying to your last comment, I don't know how I missed it. Can you tell us what specific molecules or atoms are colliding with N2, Ar or He?

Comment: They are small organic and organometallic molecules: small peptides, purely organic substances, transition metal complexes, etc.

Comment: What is a "small peptide"? Glutathione? Or insulin? How many atoms?

Comment: I'm sorry @NikeDattani, I must be more precise and accurate. All molecules I expect to with are around 20-60 atoms. Some times they might grow to 100, but for current tasks I have, not more than that.

Comment: No problem. I'm just trying to help. If it was Ar colliding with N2 you might use the program "ABC" by Dimitrios Skouteris and colleagues, but that's for A -> BC reactions. What you have is a 20-100 atom molecule colliding with N2 or Ar or He, and you want to know the cross-section for that collision?

Comment: Thank you, @NikeDattani! Yes, cross-section for collisions of N2 or Ar or He with molecules of 20-100 atoms. Because ion mobility mass spectrometry can get those values from the experiment and calculation will be a good proof of the observed geometry.

Comment: Interesting. This is not something I've done before. Have you ever seen it calculated in a previous paper? Have you searched things like "computational collision cross section" ? I just searched it and immediately found some papers:https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/jcc.25199. Are you able to see what software people use when they do this? It might be an "in-house" software, meaning the research group built it themselves and it's not open to the public but you can get it if you ask them for it. I wonder if this can be done with standard MD software like LAMMPS.

Comment: @NikeDattani, these values are calculated and examples are in the papers I mentioned in the question. I was able to find iMos software, but the reason I am asking is to get recommendations for alternatives or other approaches (iMos exists for windows and linux, probably there is something for macOS i.e.) I've never used LAMMPS but seen a lot of publications with it, I need to look into it, whether it is possible to accomplish with it)

Comment: Most of the time if something is available for linux, you can get it running in macOS in my experience.  Optionally, replace the other software that is a problem in this case, the macOS :)

Comment: Hold on, you know software for this but don't want it to be only for Windows and Linux? You need something specifically for macOS? Very few scientific computing programs are written for macOS, almost everything uses Linux! You don't have any access to a Linux machine?

Comment: @NikeDattani, I found hmos while looking into the question, and just recently, the latest version became available for macOS. I will study it and give it a try, but I am still interested if there is another option.

Comment: In your last comment, I suppose you mean iMos, not hmos. In that case, perhaps iMos can be given as an answer (even a self answer) if you don't mind. Here's a good example of what a software recommendation for iMos could look like: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1222/5, here's another: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1152/5, here's nother: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1055/5

Answer (score 7):

### iMos

iMos is Ion Mobility Software based on MATLAB parallelized code that can model Collisional Cross-Section. Tool is available for macOS, Linux and Windows and developed by Carlos Larriba-Andaluz. Installer, code comments and tutorials can be found [here](http://www.imospedia.com/imos/).